# Python 2: someIterator.next() vs. next(someIterator) :Python 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, iterator

In Python 2 iterators offer `.next()`, a callable method:

```
it = iter(xrange(10))
it.next()
> 0
it.next()
> 1
...
```

In Python 3 one has to use the built-in function `next()`:

```
it = iter(range(10))
next(it)
> 0
next(it)
> 1
...
```

Is this just "syntactic sugar"? Like making it more obvious to use `next()` by moving it into the built-in functions? Or does any advanced concept hide behind this change?

Comment: `next(..)` works both for Python 2 (2.6+) and Python 3. So use `next(..)` if possible. BTW, In Python 3, you can also use `it.__next__()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are directly asking about [PEP 3114](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/)

consider the following code:

```
class test:
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        return "next"
    def __next__(self):
        return "__next__"

x = test()
for i,thing in enumerate(x):
    print(thing)
    if i>4:
        break
```

in python 2 `next` is printed but in python 3 `__next__` is printed, since the method is being called implicitly it makes way more sense to match other implicit methods such as `__add__` or `__getitem__`, which is described in [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/).

If you are planning on using `next` explicitly then much like `len`, `iter`, `getattr`, `hash` etc. then python provides a built in function to call the implicit function for you.  At least... after PEP 3114.

Also, the [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) built-in allows you pass a default value if you don't want to throw an error if the iterable is finished which is frequently useful:

```
it = iter([])
x = next(it, "pls don't crash")
```

which couldn't really be standardized for a `.next()` method call.  As well objects such as a random number generator may define a `.next` (next number) method without necessarily wanting to be an iterator which could have left ambiguity / confusion.